# How to include category name/id in wp_query for retrieving "custom post type" from a particular category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query

Here is the code I'm using right now. It fetches the posts from all the categories in the 'sp_events' post type.

```
<?php $feat_art = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sp_events','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => 1));   while($feat_art->have_posts()) : $feat_art->the_post(); ?>
```

I want to display the posts only from a category named 'eventcat1'. 
I tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
<?php $feat_art = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sp_events','category_name'=> 'eventcat1','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => 1));   while($feat_art->have_posts()) : $feat_art->the_post(); ?>
```

How to specify either the category name or the id in the query?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @Sri: That's weird, [`category_name` is the correct way to do it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Category_Parameters). Silly thing to ask: you are sure there is at least one custom post that is attached to the `eventcat1` category, and that `eventcat1` is a regular category, not another custom taxonomy term? (If you reply, please use `@Jan` so I get a notification)

Comment: @Sri once you've followed Jan's advice if the problem remains then it would be worth you posting your code where the sp_events post type is registered.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for pointing it out. The custom post type was registered by the plugin 'Event Calendar Pro' . The Category was a custom taxonomy. Replacing 'category_name' by 'sp_events_cat' made it work.  Thanks again. ;)

Comment: Comments are not for answers. Just saying. :)

Comment: I wasn't sure if I can answer my own question. So posted the solution in the comments.

Comment: @Sri: You can also answer your own question on this site, just click the button below. Then [you can "accept" it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so others can see you are no longer searching for it. Welcome to the WordPress Stack Exchange, and I hope to see more good questions and answers from you in the future!

Comment: @Jan Thanks. I've added the solution to my own question. But I guess I cannot accept it now. => "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"  I have visited the site earlier. But this is the first time I've actually used and I'm already liking it.

Comment: @Sri: Indeed, it's to prevent you from "gaming" the system by posting fake questions, just to get the attention. In the meantime you're welcome to [answer any other open question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered)!

Comment: I understand the system. Sure. I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked.

```
<?php $feat_art = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sp_events','sp_events_cat'=> 'eventcat1','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => 1));   while($feat_art->have_posts()) : $feat_art->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Seems to have small typo - double single quote after custom taxonomy.

Comment: Oops. Yeah. I've changed it.

Comment: looks fine now. :) I could have edited that myself but decided to poke so you don't end up with that bit broken code stored somewhere.

Comment: Where is'sp_events_cat' defined, since it isn't a core wordpress query key?